# How do I save/restore the Images downloaded from json across configuration changes

Tags: android, json, android-studio

I am successfully fetching, parsing and populating views from the data gotten from JSON.

But there's a bug that's plaguing the app: inability to save and restore the populated data after configuration change.

I can successfully save and restore strings but images and formatted html is my problem.

**This is my code**

```
public class FruitDetails extends AppCompatActivity{

    private final String TAG = "FruitDetails";

    protected com.nostra13.universalimageloader.core.ImageLoader mImageLoader;


    TextView fruitTitle, fruitAuthorDate, fruitContent; 
    CircularNetworkImageView authorImg;
    ImageLoader AuthImgLoader;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_fruit_details);



        fruitTitle = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.dfruit_title);
        fruitAuthorDate = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.author_date);
        fruitContent = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.dfruit_content);
        authorImg = (CircularNetworkImageView) findViewById(R.id.author_img);


        mImageLoader = com.nostra13.universalimageloader.core.ImageLoader.getInstance();
        mImageLoader.init(ImageLoaderConfiguration.createDefault(this));

        ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
        if (actionBar != null) {
            actionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        }



        if (savedInstanceState != null) {
            fruitTitle.setText(savedInstanceState.getString("fruitTitle"));
            fruitAuthorDate.setText(savedInstanceState.getString("posAuthorDate"));
            fruitContent.setText(savedInstanceState.getString("fruitContent"));
            //fruitAuthorDate.setPar

            //Unhiding views
            fruitTitle.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            fruitAuthorDate.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            fruitContent.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            authorImg.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);


        } else {
            if (NetworkCheck.isAvailableAndConnected(this)) {
                //Calling method to load fruits
                loadFruit();
            } else {
                final Context context;
                context = this;
                final AlertDialog.Builder alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
                alertDialog.setTitle(R.string.alert_titl);
                alertDialog.setCancelable(false);
                alertDialog.setIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher);
                alertDialog.setMessage(R.string.failed_fruit);
                alertDialog.setPositiveButton(R.string.alert_retry, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        if (!NetworkCheck.isAvailableAndConnected(context)) {
                            alertDialog.show();
                        } else {
                            loadFruit();
                        }
                    }
                });
                alertDialog.setNegativeButton(R.string.alert_cancel, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        finish();
                    }
                });
                alertDialog.show();
            }
        }
    }

    private void loadFruit() {
        Log.d(TAG, "loadFruit called");

        final ProgressBar progressBar;
        progressBar = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.progress_circle);
        progressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);


        int news_id = getIntent().getIntExtra("FruitId", -1);
        Log.d(TAG, "You clicked fruit id " + news_id);

        final JsonObjectRequest jsonObjReq = new JsonObjectRequest( DetailConfig.GET_DURL + news_id, null,


                new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                        Log.d("Debug", response.toString());

                        //Unhiding views
                        fruitTitle.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                        fruitAuthorDate.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                        fruitContent.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                        authorImg.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);


                        //Dismissing progressbar;
                        if (progressBar != null) {
                            progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                        }

                        //Calling method to parse json array
                        parseFruit(response);
                    }
                },
                new Response.ErrorListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                        VolleyLog.d("", "Error: " + error.getMessage());
                    }
                });

        //Creating request queue
        RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);

        //Adding request to queue
        requestQueue.add(jsonObjReq);
    }

    //This method will parse json data of fruit
    private void parseFruit(JSONObject jsonObject) {

        Log.d(TAG, "Parsing fruit");


            try {
                String title = jsonObject.getString(DetailConfig.TAG_DFRUIT_TITLE);
                fruitTitle.setText(Html.fromHtml(title));

                JSONObject pAuthor = jsonObject.getJSONObject("author");
                String author = pAuthor.getString("name");
                String authorimg = pAuthor.getString("avatar");

                AuthImgLoader = VolleyRequest.getInstance(getApplicationContext()).getImageLoader();
                AuthImgLoader.get(authorimg, ImageLoader.getImageListener(authorImg, R.drawable.ic_author, R.drawable.ic_author));
                authorImg.setImageUrl(authorimg, AuthImgLoader);


                SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd MMMM, yyyy");
                SimpleDateFormat inputFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss");
                String inputDateStr = jsonObject.getString(DetailConfig.TAG_DFRUIT_DATE);
                try {
                    Date inputDate = inputFormat.parse(inputDateStr);
                    String date = dateFormat.format(inputDate);
                    Resources resources = getResources();
                    String authdate= String.format(resources.getString(R.string.fruit_by), author, date);
                    fruitAuthorDate.setText(authdate);
                } catch (ParseException e) {
                    Log.d(TAG, "Error in parsing date");
                }

                String content = jsonObject.getString(DetailConfig.TAG_DFRUIT_CONTENT);
                Spanned spanned = Html.fromHtml(content, new UILImageGetter(fruitContent, this), null);
                fruitContent.setText(spanned);

            } catch (JSONException w) {
                w.printStackTrace();
            }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
        super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
        outState.putString("fruitTitle", fruitTitle.getText().toString());
        outState.putString("posAuthorDate", fruitAuthorDate.getText().toString());
        outState.putString("fruitContent", fruitContent.getText().toString());
        //Doesn't work --> outState.putParcelable("fruitAuthor", (Parcelable) fruitAuthorDate);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onSupportNavigateUp() {
        onBackPressed();
        return true;
    }

}
```

From the code above I can save and restore `fruitTitle` and `fruitAuthorDate` because they contain only strings.
For `fruitContent` it contains text that is `Spanned`, formatted with `Html.fromHtml`, and contains downloaded images so the code above only succeeds in saving and restoring strings and strings alone.
Upon restore, the `Html.fromHtml` formatted text is replaced by unformatted string and the images are gone!

For `fruitAuthorDate` I couldn't save it at all. I tried parcalables as you can see above but the app crashed.

So, my question is how do I save these images and styled html text when the screen is rotated?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of saving single fields of your JSON data, you could simply just save the whole `JSONObject` that you get from the request.

In your `onResponse()` callback of the `JsonObjectRequest` you just save your `JSONObject` to some field that I'll call `fruitData`:

```
new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
    @Override
    public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
        ...

        fruitData = response; // where fruitData is a JSONObject field of your activity

        parseFruit(response);
    }
}
```

Then in `onSaveInstanceState()` you simply save the `JSONObject fruitData` as a string to the bundle.

```
protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
    outState.putString("fruitData", fruitData.toString());
}
```

To recover the data, you can get the data back in `onCreate()` as you already do with the single fields, and call `parseFruit()` on it as if you have downloaded it before:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    ...

    if (savedInstanceState != null) {
        try {
            String fruitDataStr = savedInstanceState.getString("fruitData");
            fruitData = new JSONObject(fruitDataStr);

            parseFruit(fruitData);
        }
        catch (JSONException e) { }

        //Unhiding views
        fruitTitle.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        fruitAuthorDate.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        fruitContent.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        authorImg.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    } 
    ...
}
```

On a side note: I would put the "Unhiding views" logic into the `parseFruit()` method, so you just have that code once, not twice as now in `onCreate()` and `onResponse()`.

Comment: where and how should  I declare `fruitData` field ?

Comment: @Ozuf just like `ImageLoader AuthImgLoader;` at the top of your `FruitDetails` Activity, for example `private JSONObject fruitData;`

Comment: I did this `private String fruitData` before `onCreate`and Android Studio began to complain of "Incompatible types" in line `fruitData = response;`

Comment: @Ozuf It's a `JSONObject` not a `String`

Comment: it works but there's a little problem, if there is internet connectivity after rotation, it works file. But I purposely offed my data just before rotation and guess what? Every other thing restored except the images in `fruitContent`.

Comment: @Ozuf Looks like the images are not cached. You seem to use a `UILImageGetter`. I don't know that, but you may look up whether it supports image caching..

Comment: I'm using UniversalImageDownloader. I have enabled caching so the images are being restore now; thanks for pointing that out to me. But another problem resurfaced, after restore, some path of the text (from the buttom) in `fruitContent` is cut off and won't even appear if I rotate back to portrait.

Answer (score 0):

You can use retained fragment as a container for the data you want survive configuration change. Check http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/runtime-changes.html#RetainingAnObject